# WinAPI BluetoothFindFirstDevice in C# don't return any result

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, bluetooth, dllimport

I need to scan bluetooth devices from C# via `pageBluetoothFindFirstDevice`
I create a shared library project
I type

```
[DllImport("irprops.cpl", SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr BluetoothFindFirstDevice(ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS searchParams, ref BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo);
```

and structures

Code for call WinAPI

```
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS param = new BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS()
param.dwSize = 248;
param.fIssueInquiry = true;
param.fReturnAuthenticated = true;
param.fReturnConnected = true;
param.fReturnRemembered = true;
param.fReturnUnknown = true;
param.hRadio = IntPtr.Zero;
param.cTimeoutMultiplier = 1;
BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO deviceInfo = new BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO();
IntPtr handle = BluetoothFindFirstDevice(ref param, ref deviceInfo);
```

but I don't see any devices in `param` and `handle` return `NULL`

also, I check this WinAPI on Flutter via `dart:ffi` and I see my device

Can you say what I do wrong?

Comment: You did not setup search params. Refer to API documentation to find out how it must be done.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I try add it. But I don't see any changes (

Comment: deviceInfo.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_INFO)); Also its always good idea to provide valid Radio handle.

Comment: Params.dwSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_SEARCH_PARAMS));

Comment: cTimeoutMultiplier = 1 - executes discovering in 1.28 seconds (nothing will be found). As I wrote, refer to docs and you'll find that: cTimeoutMultiplier

A value that indicates the time out for the inquiry, expressed in increments of 1.28 seconds. For example, an inquiry of 12.8 seconds has a cTimeoutMultiplier value of 10. The maximum value for this member is 48.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko I try set your params, but nothing changed (

Comment: GetLastError() shows what is going wrong. Or use third-party libs (32feet or Bluetooth Framework) what is much faster and simple.

Comment: I cannot use 32feet in my project (((

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247340/discussion-between-mike-petrichenko-and-nikolay).

Comment: According to [BluetoothFindFirstDevice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bluetoothapis/nf-bluetoothapis-bluetoothfindfirstdevice) , these two structures' `dwSize` member should be set correctly And Call the [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) function for more information on the error.

Comment: Please post all your definitions (structs, etc) so we can check your code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example